# combine authentication server and resource server requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, https, amazon-cognito

Currently my application uses API requests to an amazon Cognito server (authentication server) to get auth tokens and when the application initializes it sends an API request to an amazon resource server to get some user details. But I want to combine these two API calls and reduce the loading time for the application when it loads.

API call for cognito server:

```
https://cognito-idp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/
body:
{
   "AuthParameters" : {
      "USERNAME" : "...",
      "PASSWORD" : "..."
   },
   "AuthFlow" : "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
   "ClientId" : "..."
}
```

API call for resource server:

```
{{base_url}}/user/flag
with auth token
```

Is there any possible way to combine above two requests?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [ID Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html) Payload (claims) in order to store/get the data you need, it can contain custom attributes that you define in your user pool. From docs:

> - The ID token contains claims about their identity, like their user
>   name, family name, and email address.
> - The ID token can also contain custom attributes that you define in your user pool.

You mentioned you only get some user details from another resource. So you should consider if:

1. you want to store the required data in cognito claims (custom or standard) or,
2. you still want to store it in the current service because (for example) it's data that changes frequently

Either case research about limitations, you can [start here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html) with special attention for [custom attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes).

For the **second case** you could customize the user pool workflow with a [lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html). Implement a *[Pre token generation Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html)* in which you can customize an identity token before Amazon Cognito generates it. Again, check lambda triggers limitations.